# Malware popup - how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

The past couple of days I've been periodically getting this pop up through my antivirus. I'm not familiar with what to do with malware but I have made sure there are no recently installed apps- I have uninstalled and reinstalled my Chrome- 'reset' and 'repaired' the automatic windows edge and yet it still pops up.

I don't know what to do from here and I'm really hoping someone can help me.

[image: picture of the popup]